# Changing data-caption in FancyBox 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-3

[image: Example]

I need to replace data-caption width right white box with custom comments area.

Comment: where is your code! please share your code here

Comment: <div class="col-lg-3 gallery-image-holder">
     <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="assets/images/gallery/1.jpg" data-caption='aaa'>
      <img src="assets/images/gallery/1.jpg">
     </a>
    </div>
There is no specific code, I was surfing internet and couldn`t find any way to change it, that`s why I asked here

Comment: Read plugin documents , I think they are provided this type of information

Comment: Try to look at source code of the similar demo found at homepage. Basically, just play with CSS, you can easily change position of each block.

Comment: I wrote my own, thanks by the way!!